# Svg is not displaying - shadow-root

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a `<template>` with an SVG inside it and I am trying to add the template to the DOM.
The template is added successfully - but the svg is hidden for some reason. Without templates, it works fine!

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="output"></div>

<template id="template">
    <li>
        <svg class="...>
            <use href="./icons.svg#icon"></use>
        </svg>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</template>
```

**JS**:

```js
const $output = document.getElementById('output');

// Clone template of auto complete addresses container
const $otherTemplate = $other.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

// Select the list container inside the template
const $list = $otherTemplate.querySelector('ul')

const $template = document.getElementById('template');

const $sugTemplate = $template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

$list.appendChild($sugTemplate);

$output.appendChild($otherTemplate);
```

**RESULT**:

[image]

Comment: If you need to be able to inspect the shadow DOM please take a look at this article: [Inspecting the Shadow DOM using Google Chrome](https://oliversmith.io/technology/2012/05/19/inspecting-the-shadow-dom-in-google-chrome-inspector/)

Comment: I understand, but still it doesn't help me with the real issue - the icon is not presented in the DOM.

Comment: May not be the problem here, but `<li>` can only be the child of an `<ul>`, an `<ol>` or a `<menu>` element. Please try to provide valid HTML markup as much as possible.

Comment: After fixing a few things, I managed to produce a repro here: https://plnkr.co/edit/Yiuem9MuNoT0dKFs?open=lib%2Fscript.js Works well in FF -> that's a chrome bug, [here is their issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/). And here is a [more minimal version](https://plnkr.co/edit/GRD2g6kd7JEPSHNN?open=lib%2Fscript.js) Also let them know that it only concerns external references: [the ones made to the doc itself work well](https://plnkr.co/edit/CwcBbh1kDDBZ79ST?open=lib%2Fscript.js).

Comment: @Kaiido thanks. I have put the `li` in `ul` (you can see i put the template in other template).

Answer (score 0):

That's a chrome bug.

Bug report has been created:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1099181